# Fetching results ordered by latest child in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a table companys and a table messages.
Now I want to show the user a list of companys ordered by the latest message.
So when a companys sends a message to the user that company is on top of the list until another company sends a message.

I used the following sql query for the android version

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    c.id, c.title, c.otherfields
    m.title as lastMessageIntro,
    m.timestamp as lastMessageTimestamp,
    CASE WHEN rm.read IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE rm.read END AS noNewMessage 
FROM Company c
LEFT JOIN Message m ON c.id = m.id
LEFT JOIN Message rm ON c.id = rm.id AND rm.read = 0
WHERE m.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY m.timestamp) as t1
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY lastMessageTimestamp DESC;
```

I am new to iOS and CoreData and unable to do this or something similar. Who can point me in de right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the companies using the following predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY messages.read = %@", @NO];
```

and this sort descriptor

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"@max.messages.timestamp" ascending:NO]
```

As you can see by the strike-through above, you cannot use the `@max` aggregate operator in sort descriptors. You could have a transient property though, as follows:

Add a new attribute `lastMessageDate` to the Company entity, make it non-*transient* and optional and program its getter to retrieve the latest message.

```
-(NSDate *)lastMessageDate {

    if (!self.messages.count) { 
       return nil; 
    }

    NSArray *sorted = [self.messages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
       @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES]]];
    return [sorted.lastObject timestamp];
}
```

You may also need to override the getters that affect this property.

But now you can use this sortDescriptor:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastMessageDate" ascending:NO];
```

Comment: That seems not to work, it crashes with `uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath @max.messages.timestamp not found in entity`. I assume that aggregate operators like `@max` do not work in a Core Data sort descriptor.

Comment: Wow Martin, you actually wrote a test for this - great! I have to think about this some more.

Comment: Yes, there were some similar questions in the past, and I haven't found a simple solution yet.

Comment: Did you test the new solution? As far as I know, transient attributes cannot be used in a Core Data sort descriptor!

Comment: @MartinR Is `NSDictionaryResultType` with `@max.messages.timestamp` and `setPropertiesToGroupBy:` will help?

Comment: This is not realy the sollution I expected but it works and apparently there isn't realy a simpeler sollution so thanks!

Comment: @speedrock Please try my solution *without* making the attribute transient. I think this should work.

Comment: Btw it sould be `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` instead of `sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors`

The code works however the ordering isn't updated when the data changes so it's close but not working completely. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: When the data changes you can call `[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil]; [self.tableView reloadData];` to update the list.